# DateTime.TryParse is not properly checking the time portion of a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, tryparse

I'm using `DateTime.TryParse(value, out datetime)` to check if a string have a valid date. 
But I have a problem. If value is time format (ex: 14:25:26), then `Datetime.TryParse` returns true. This is not what I expect.
How can I fix this?

Comment: 14:25:26 is a valid time. That is 2:25:26 PM.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but you should add more sample code and your expected result.

Comment: Not really clear why you think value is invalid and what you actually want to verify. Reading documentation may help, but at very least edit the question with your expectations and goals so answers can be voted on/added.

Answer (score 1):

This will indeed return true, and that's expected. The value of `dt` ends up with the current date.

```
DateTime dt;
var result = DateTime.TryParse("14:25:26", out dt);
```

If you want a string that contains only a time to be invalid, you could use `TryParseExact` instead.

```
DateTime dt;
var result = DateTime.TryParseExact("14:25:26", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
// result is False, since the string does not contain a date
```